# How to retrieve the blob/file from ImagePicker in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi the object returned by `ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'` do not contains any file, I am not sure how to convert the data returned to blob/file, do I have to write the data to file? Creating a second file like

```
 const data = new FormData()
 data.append('file', source)
```

anyway my code

```
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        quality: 0.8
      })
      if (!result.cancelled) {
       console.log('Image ', source)
      }
```

I got this when I console log

> Image  Object {   "cancelled": false,   "height": 750,   "type":
>   "image",   "uri":
>   "file:///Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3DE97E67-7232-4945-BE1C-50C09FED6116/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C84C698-8C77-4D64-85AC-BFB0E88CBA0F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540usfslk%252Fwillapprn/ImagePicker/19ED3307-DE54-4A09-A081-7DD32993E46B.jpg",
>   "width": 1124, }

I could add `base64` to the options and get it on response but why would I convert base64 to image if it already exist? my issue is that google firestore do not recognize the data sent

```
FirebaseStorageError {
  "code_": "storage/invalid-argument",
  "message_": "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.",
  "name_": "FirebaseError",
  "serverResponse_": null,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if anyone looking for the answer later on, here's a great function

[Example of how to upload image in expo with react-native and firebase](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/expo-rn-firebase-image-upload)

```
 const response = await fetch(result.uri);
 const blob = await response.blob();
 this.uploadImage(blob)
```

Comment: but this doesn't work on android. it throws some "network fail" error.

Comment: Yes because this answer assumes that fetch in browser works the same way as fetch in react-native environment. You probably get that .blob() is not a function.